# How was Ender already 10 while on the lake?

Tags: enders-game, continuity

Ender was promoted to commander of Dragon Army, when he was nine and a half.

> "Content. He's doing well. His mind is keen, his play is excellent. Young as he is. we've never had a boy better prepared for command. Usually they go at eleven. but at nine and a half he's top flight."

He was with Dragon Army for two months:

> There was no guarantee that they'd give him the usual three months to get his army together before sending them into battle.
>
> ---
>
> "We've still got a month to go before our training period is normally supposed to end. About time we started doing formations.

And then he was on Earth for 3 months.

> So that's why you brought me here, thought Ender. With all your hurry, that's why you took three months, to make me love Earth.

That would make him be 9 years old, going on 10 when he meets Valentine.
So why does Valentine say that Ender was 10?

> She got in the car. "Ender's only ten years old," she said. "I thought
> you told us the first time he'd be eligible for a leave was when he was twelve."

Did she forget how old he was? (Not likely as she would celebrate his birthday every year with her small fires.)

And later, while in the tug journey to Eros:

> Five years. Only five years until the fleet arrives, and I don't know anything yet, "I'll only be fifteen in five years," Ender said.
>
> "Going on sixteen," said Graff. "It all depends on what you know."

But the tug took a total of only 3 months,

> "Oh, no, of course not. I.E. Command is on the minor planet Eros, which should be about three months away from here at the highest possible speed. Which is the speed you'll use, of course."

So even if the conversation took place at the end of the Journey Ender would only be a month or two over the age of ten. Why does Graff say that he would be "going on sixteen" in five years?

Comment: Why the downvote? It's a perfectly fine question.

Comment: Seems excessive nitpicking to me.  When people say nine and a half they don't usually mean 9.50 years.  People just aren't that precise generally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, Ender was 9 1/2, which isn't the same as saying exactly 9.5 years or 9 years and 6 months. When ages are given in "halves" that generally means approximately that age, or at *least* the half age, but not yet the full age. That is to say, you can be at the "half" age for at least 6 months.

So, by my guess, Ender was at least 9 years and 7 months, *if* all time was precisely accounted for.

Secondly, Graff was correcting likely correcting his time estimates to Ender. Much like the half-age rule, time estimates given in years don't generally mean that exact amount of time. So, Graff's comment that Ender would be going on sixteen (which is some indeterminate number of months before sixteen), means that the 5 year estimate is probably a little further off than exactly 5 years, by however many months it takes for Ender to be "going on sixteen".

In general, specific accounts of time aren't given in the story. We see a few months pass here and there, specifically mentioned, but there aren't hard dates given for most activities. It's best not to view these as inconsistencies, but as general vagueness, as the details aren't pertinent to the narrative.

Comment: It would surprise you how many specific amounts of time are given in Ender's Game. The only specifics that can't be figured out is when he switches from Rat to Phoenix. (He switches to Rat army 3 days after his 7th birthday fights at least 6 battles there, then the narrative switches to Peter and Valentine when he turns 8 and by the time that it switches back, Ender is already 9 and a toon leader in Phoenix.)

Comment: @ibid I'm not surprised. Those are not dates, those are indicators of passage of time. You don't see birth dates, launch dates, etc.

Comment: Ender's birthday is in the Fall, Valentine's is in the Summer, and Peter's is in the Winter or so. They get older at different times. (I might be a bit off as I don't have my notes in front of me.) All evidence goes to Card having worked out a very detailed chronology.

Comment: In general, yes the only references to the time of year is Ender's 8th birthday (Fall), Ender returning to Earth (hot summer), and it that it hasn't gotten cold yet 3 months later on the lake.

Comment: @ibid A writer is likely to have a chronology, for internal consistency. It doesn't mean the exact dates are necessary for the story. None of the examples you've given include *dates*, only time frames.  Anyway, if you think Card has a detailed chronology, why would you think he would have messed it up? It's been long enough now for it to have been corrected in modern editions, if they were truly errors.

Comment: I don't think that he messed it up. Your answer works with the 9 1/2 being 7 or 8 months. Also the changes made to published editions of Ender's Game over the years have been few, and were mostly towards making the book politically correct. There is a revised edition that Card had promised back in 2008 which hasn't yet been released.